# How to set server port with org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, jetty

I am currently setting the port via a `jetty.xml` file and I've been trying to figure out from the new documentation how to actually define an `httpConnector` through the Maven plugin's configuration. The docs on Eclipse's site seem a bit vague on it and I've been trying to figure this out for a while, thus ending up using a `jetty.xml`. I'd like to find out the proper way to do this now.

I'm currently using `org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.1.v20140609`.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The [`jetty-maven-plugin` documentation (for *jetty 11* at the time of this answer - update)](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-11/programming_guide.php) states that you can either configure the `httpConnector` element in the *pom.xml* file to setup the `ServerConnector` preferences or use the `jetty.http.port` system property to change the port or use the Jetty descriptor i.e. the way you are doing it actually.

Then you have several options:

#### *(Java) System Property:*

Change the port when just running your application through the *mvn* command:

```
mvn jetty:run -Djetty.http.port=9999
```

#### *(Maven) Project Property:*

1. Set the property inside your project *pom.xml* descriptor file:

   ```
    <properties>
      <jetty.http.port>9999</jetty.http.port>
    </properties>
   ```
2. Then just run your application through the *Jetty plugin* and the port will be picked up automatically:

   mvn jetty:run

#### *(Maven) Jetty Plugin Configuration:*

Set the port in your plugin declaration inside the *pom.xml* file:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>9.2.1.v20140609</version>
      <configuration>
        <httpConnector>
          <!--host>localhost</host-->
          <port>9999</port>
        </httpConnector>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

### EDIT

In new versions of [`jetty-maven-plugin`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), `jetty.http.port` is the default port property and `jetty.port` won't work as in previous plugin versions.

Comment: The system property `jetty.port` din't work for me. However the httpConnector worked. Can you also please add the jetty-maven-plugin documentation?.

Comment: Thanks @Lucky for pointing that out. I think the `jetty.port` property is now depreacated in favor of `jetty.http.port`. The answer has been updated to mirror changes in the plugin documentation.

Comment: I have no luck with -Djetty.http.port=9999 but  with -Djetty.port=9999 instead

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Just to say that in Intellij it got it wrong, guess it is a bug. But it works fine running the command mvn!

Answer (score 26):

Run following command:
**mvn jetty:run -Djetty.port=9999**

I guess ***mvn jetty:run -Djetty.http.port=9999*** is deprecated. It didn't work for me.

Comment: How is this answer any different, or better than the accepted one?

Comment: Confirmed, with plugin.jetty.maven.version=9.1.4.v20140401 it is jetty.port; jetty.http.port, from accepted answer, des not work.

Answer (score 17):

You may configure the port through the `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.1.v20140609</version>
            <configuration>
                <httpConnector>
                    <port>9999</port>
                </httpConnector>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, confirmed as I am currently debugging the server in my chrome on port 8088.

```
 mvn jetty:run -Dhttp.port=8088
```

Comment: For the reference of future users: which version of the plugin are you using? (Could you specify the GAV coordinates)?

Answer (score 0):

By Default Jetty runs on 8080 port, if any application like oracle DB using that port in your system then Jetty server will not start and gives some BIND exception. to overcome this if your project is maven project then in pom.xml file use below code, then it works perfectly(here i am using port 8888 which is free in my system)

```
<!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
                running jetty:run on the command line. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                     <httpConnector>
                    <host>localhost</host>
                     <port>8888</port>
                     </httpConnector>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: after adding above code in your pom.xml  file access the jetty server in any browser using http://localhost:8888/

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectors>
    <connector>
        <port>9999</port>
    </connector>
</connectors>
```

in pom.xml file

Comment: the above code goes in the plugins -> plugin -> configuration tags of pom.xml file

Comment: Under your answer, there is a small link titled "edit". You can use that to modify your answer. Please update your answer with the explanation from your above comment.