# How do I set the port using maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm using Maven from the command line on Windows, but I don't need to necessarily change the port from the command line specifically.

Running the command

```
mvn -Djetty.http.port=8000 exec:java
```

results in the following output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The project com.google.apis-samples:oauth2-cmdline-sample:jar:1 
uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not 
for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-
enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-
rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Building Example for the OAuth2 API using JSON and OAuth 2.0 1
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------- 
----
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) > validate @ oauth2-
cmdline-sample >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) < validate @ oauth2-
cmdline-sample <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) @ oauth2-cmdline-sample       
---
Jun 19, 2017 5:09:53 PM 
com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory 
setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: 
C:\Users\roxlala\.store\oauth2_sample
Jun 19, 2017 5:09:53 PM 
com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory 
setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: 
C:\Users\roxlala\.store\oauth2_sample
2017-06-19 17:09:53.229:INFO::Logging to STDERR via 
org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2017-06-19 17:09:53.229:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
2017-06-19 17:09:53.259:INFO::Started SocketConnector@localhost:1871
Please open the following address in your browser:
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=<my-id>.
googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http: 
//localhost:1871/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis. 
com/auth
/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
Attempting to open that address in the default browser now...
```

Comment: What port are you talking about?

Comment: port for serving my app on the localhost, like localhost:8000 for example

Comment: Using what plugin? Vanilla maven does not serve applications.

Comment: I downloaded maven from the maven website. Then I am using the command "mvn -q exec:java" in the command line to try to look at some of Google's samples of usage of some Google APIs using Java. It says the following. I guess Jetty is the plugin that is doing the serving. 2017-06-19 17:03:41.782:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
2017-06-19 17:03:41.867:INFO::Started SocketConnector@localhost:1423

Comment: Give `mvn -Djetty.http.port=8000 exec:java` a try. That's the standard way of specifying the port for the Jetty plugin. It is however possible that the Jetty server is governed by the application and not maven, in which case you'd have to provide more details about the application you're trying to run.

Comment: The app that I am trying to run is here, the oauth2-cmdline-sample. https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples

Comment: Anything I should look for specifically? It has a pom.xml file. Perhaps editing that would be the solution

Comment: Looks like you're SOL. The sample instantiates the Jetty server using [`new LocalServerReceiver()`](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/oauth2-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/oauth2/cmdline/OAuth2Sample.java), which, according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/extensions/jetty/auth/oauth2/LocalServerReceiver) just selects an unused port. Why does it matter anyway, since you're only running samples?

Comment: I've tried the solutions from here, but nothing works for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644036/how-to-set-server-port-with-org-eclipse-jettyjetty-maven-plugin

Comment: It matters because I get this error. The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:1958/Callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. It seems that I need to know the port number that I'm going to be using when setting up my OAuth keys with the Google API

Comment: What is SOL? Couldn't find that via Google search.

Comment: Shit out of luck :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set server port with org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644036/how-to-set-server-port-with-org-eclipse-jettyjetty-maven-plugin)

Comment: @Joe It's not the plugin doing the serving, it's the application itself.

Comment: Just edit the code and change the call from `new LocalServerReceiver()` to `new LocalServerReceiver("localhost", 8000, "/Callback", null, null)`

Comment: Still using a random port.